# can't change sddm display manager theme

Tags: debian-buster, display-manager

I am using Debian 10 with Xfce desktop environment. I recently changed to sddm display manager. However no matter what I do, I can't change the display manager **theme** (only the debian-maui theme appears).
I want to change the theme to a custom one which I have downloaded from git hub (I tested it using `sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme [theme location]` command and it works fine).  Can anyone explain me **clearly** how to do it? (There were no sddm config files to be found and even when I manually created them, they seem to have no effect on the theme of the display manager despite whatever necessary changes made to the config file)

[Please keep in mind I use Xfce desktop environment]

Comment: better to post on Unix/Linux or Super User sibling sites, since SO is for programming questions

Comment: @underscore_d ok

Comment: So if anyone comes across this problem. The solution is this. Copy the contents of the following file https://github.com/lxqt/sddm-config-editor/blob/master/data/example.conf and paste it in /etc/sddm.conf (If there is no file named sddm.conf create one)

Comment: To change theme, copy your theme folder to /usr/share/sddm/themes 》 move the previous theme folder to some other place 》 rename your current theme folder to that of the previous theme folder name 》 Now open /etc/sddm.conf 》 under the  [Themes] section, enter your theme folder name next to ```Current=``` . For example, if the theme folder name in /usr/share/sddm/themes is debian-maui, change the value to ```Current=debian-maui```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS new sddm themes you can find by:

```
apt search sddm-theme
```

and instll it by e.g.:

```
sudo apt install sddm-theme-lubuntu
```

After instalation new theme will be placed in `/usr/share/sddm/themes/`
In the same dir there is a link:

```
ubuntu-theme -> /etc/alternatives/sddm-ubuntu-theme/
```

pointing to `/etc/alternatives/sddm-ubuntu-theme`

In `/etc/alternatives` there is a link you can change to point to theme you like, e.g.:

```
 /etc/alternatives/sddm-ubuntu-theme -> /usr/share/sddm/themes/maldives/
```

and this link specifies default config

To check where and which is the system default config file placed in you can run:

```
sddm --example-config
```

and analyze [Theme] section.